# Flutter - Delete item from list issue

Tags: flutter

I am trying to remove a items from a list OnPressed

The widget item looks like this

```
Flexible(
   flex: 1,
   fit: FlexFit.tight,
   child: IconButton(
   iconSize: 16.0,
   color: Colors.green[800],
   icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
   onPressed: () => _deleteMaltFromList(gram[index],colors[index],maltname[index], index, procedure[index]),
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
```

The void looks like this (the index and procedure have values):

```
void _deleteMaltFromList(index, procedure){
   
    print(index);
    print(procedure);

    setState(() {
      procedure.remove(index[index]);
    });
  }
```

This gives the error:
Class 'int' has no instance method '[]'.
Receiver: 0
Tried calling:

If I try for call the remove in the widget like below - I works fine

```
Flexible(
   flex: 1,
   fit: FlexFit.tight,
   child: IconButton(
   iconSize: 16.0,
   color: Colors.green[800],
   icon: Icon(Icons.delete),

   onPressed: (){
   setState(() {
                                                               
      procedure.remove(procedure[index], index);
             });
             },
),
   ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `index` is an `int`, then `index[index]` makes no sense, since `int` has no `[]` method.  `procedure` clearly has a `[]` method, and succeeds both for `.remove` and `[]`.

Comment: If I in the void call
procedure.remove[index];

Then I get this error:
Class 'String' has no instance getter 'remove'.
Receiver: "T"

Comment: Huh?  "the index and procedure have values".  What values?  What types?  Sounds like procedure is now a string not a list.

Comment: Thanks Randal - I did not notice that the where a string after the void call - Thanks a lot it works now

Answer (score 1):

**List.remove()**

The `List.remove()` function removes the first occurrence of the specified item in the list. This function returns true if the specified value is removed from the list.

```
List.remove(Object value)
```

**value** − represents the value of the item that should be removed from the list.
The following example shows how to use this function :
**Code :**

```
void main() { 
   List l = [1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; 
   print('The value of list before removing the list element ${l}'); 
   bool res = l.remove(1); 
   print('The value of list after removing the list element ${l}'); 
}
```

**Output :**

```
The value of list before removing the list element [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 
The value of list after removing the list element [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

You can learn more about **[here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_removing_list_items.htm)**